Solve the matrix equation $A = - B A B^T + C$ without matrix inversion or vectorization
Let $B$ and $C$ be two $n \times n$ matrices, which may or may not be nicely behaved. I would like to solve for the matrix $A$ in the following equation:
$$
A = -B A B^T + C
$$
This equation is linear in $A$, and so in principle it should be perfectly solvable. However, I'm finding it numerically difficult to do so in a well-behaved way. Here's what I've tried so far:

If $n$ isn't so large, we can easily solve for $A$ by vectorizing the equation. Using quantum-mechanical bra-ket notation for convenience, we have
$$
|A\rangle = - (B \otimes B) |A \rangle + |C\rangle \implies |A \rangle = [\mathbb{1} + B \otimes B]^{-1} |C\rangle
$$
which can then be un-vectorized to obtain $A$. Unfortunately, this approach is totally intractable if $n$ is large, since vectorization will be impossible.

If $B = SD S^{-1}$ can be easily diagonalized, with $D = \text{diag}(d_1, \ldots , d_n)$ a diagonal matrix, then the problem is again perfectly solvable. Defining $A_S = S^{-1} A (S^T)^{-1}$ (and similarly defining $C_S$), then the simplified equation $A_S = -D A_S D + C_S$ allows us to immediately solve for the matrix elements of $A_S$:
$$
[A_S]_{ij} = \frac{[C_S]_{ij}}{1 + d_i d_j}
$$
(The relation to the previous solution via vectorization is readily apparent.) Then we can simply transform back to obtain $A = S A_S S^T$. Unfortunately, I'm finding that in the particular problem I am working with, $B$ appears to be difficult to diagonalize. I'm not 100% sure why, since I don't know a ton about numerical linear algebra; but it's condition number doesn't look particularly bad (I have an example with $24 \times 24$ matrices where all of the singular values of $B$ are between 0.015 and 2, and yet I am still running into difficulties).

I've also tried solving via iteration; essentially I set $A_0 = 0$ and $A_k = -BA_{k-1} B^T + C$ for $k \geq 1$. Unfortunately I don't seem to obtain convergence as $k$ increases, either for randomly chosen $B$ and $C$ or for the matrices in my particular problem.


So, my question is: is there any obvious way to solve this equation which doesn't involve vectorization, or explicitly diagonalizing $B$?

have you tried iteration with a damping term?

I haven't; can adding a damping term help me find a self-consistent solution to the undamped problem?

This is the Stein matrix equation also known as the discrete time Lyapunov matrix equation.
Your analysis using the Kronecter product form shows that the equation has a unique solution $X$ for every choice of $C$ provided $1 + \lambda \mu \not = 0$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$ of $B$.
In particular, if spectral radius of $B$ satisfies $\rho(B) < 1$ or if the spectral norm of $B$ satisfies $\|B\|_2 < 1$, then the iteration that you have explored will converge to the solution $A = \sum_{j=0}^\infty B^j C (B^T)^j$.
In the general case you can solve the problem by reducing $B$ to (complex) Schur form $B = USU^*$. Your equation $A + BAB^* = C$ is transformed into the equivalent form
$$ X + S X S^* = U^*CU$$
where the new unknown is $X = U^* A U$. You can now compute the columns of $X$ one-by-one using backsubstitution provided that you start with last column and move toward the first column. This the Bartel-Stewart algorithm adapted to the Stein equation.

Glad to know that the problem has a name! Quick question: does it matter that the matrices are generally complex, but the equation in my problem has a real transpose? I assume what you write as $B^*$ is the conjugate-transpose (physicists usually write $B^{\dagger}$), but in my problem it's really $A + B A B^T = C$ even though $A,B,C$ are generally complex.

@Zack: This does not present a problem. The key is the triangular structure of the coefficient matrices. If the equation is changed to $X + RXS= T$ where $R$ is upper triangular and $S$ is lower triangular and $T$ is general, then you can still recover the columns of $X$ one-by-one from right to left using backsubstution. If you must keep the matrices and the calculations real, then replace the complex Schur form with the real Schur form.

I just implemented your solution, it works perfectly! Thank you so much.

@Zack Your are very welcome.
